# How can I fix php-fpm info by homebrew-php

Tags: php, git

I've just installed php in osx by using homebrew with command like this.

```
$ brew install --without-apache --with-fpm --with-mysql php55
```

After install I got a following messeage.

> To have launchd start php55 at login:
>       ln -sfv /usr/local/opt/php55/*.plist ~/Library/LaunchAgents Then to load php55 now:
>       launchctl load ~/Library/LaunchAgents/homebrew.mxcl.php55.plist

But the last sentence should be `launchctl load ~/Library/LaunchAgents/homebrew-php.josegonzalez.php55.plist`. This issue is already in github issue page.

https://github.com/josegonzalez/homebrew-php/issues/663

I thought it's only small change of text, so I forked the project and by `git clone`, cloned to local. And looked for the place the text is written by like this.

```
find . -type f -name "*.*" -print0 | xargs -0 grep "mxcl"
./Contributions/Using FPM.md:0. `brew update && brew pull https://github.com/mxcl/homebrew/pull/12093`
./Contributions/Using FPM.md:For PHP-FPM to work with OS X built-in Apache, you need to install mod_fastcgi. There is a formula for that at https://github.com/mxcl/homebrew/pull/12093 (hopefully, soon within Homebrew).
./Contributions/Using FPM.md:    brew pull https://github.com/mxcl/homebrew/pull/12093
./Formula/abstract-php.rb:      opoo "INTL is broken as of mxcl/homebrew#03ed757c, please install php#{php_version_path.to_s}-intl" unless build_intl?
./Formula/abstract-php.rb:      icu4c is broken as of mxcl/homebrew#03ed757c, so you will need to install intl as
./README.md:This repository contains **PHP-related** formulae for [Homebrew](https://github.com/mxcl/homebrew).
```

As far as I can see, there is nothing related to the instruction text.
Am I completely wrong path to solve the problem like this?

I want to know there is more effective way to find the text, or should I read the code line by line to find the place?